# I have many input tags, and each input tag is having a ul from where a list element can be selected to insert value in to the input field

Tags: javascript

But the problem is when i have added onclick events to each input tag that close the ul on blur and open the ul on focus by using display none and block respectively. As i am blurring each time on input blur the event listener for ul is not working. here is the code.

```
 var selectTime= document.querySelectorAll("input");
    for( var i=0; i<selectTime.length; i++) {
                selectTime[i].onfocus = function(event) {
                    var el = event.currentTarget;
                 el.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";//ul is show
            }
    }
    for( var i=0; i<selectTime.length; i++) {
                selectTime[i].onblur = function(event) {
                var el = event.currentTarget;
                el.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";//ul is none
                }
    }
    for(i=0;i<ulElements.length;i++){
    ulElements[i].onclick= function(event){
                if (event.target.tagName === 'LI'){
                    console.log(event.target);  
                }
        }
    }
```

But the element selected from ul li is not displaying in console

here is an demo https://jsfiddle.net/fzbx36zf/

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not displaying anything, i think the problem is i m making the list ul as none , so nothing is displaying. ok i will share demo

Comment: added demo in jsfiddle

Comment: You should post the code here as a runnable snippet, links rot. What you have posted at jsfiddle is entirely different to the code here, and does not seem to have any issues. Please edit the title to something meaningful, the entire question should be in the body, not spread across the title and body.

Answer (score 0):

As `click-event` is invoked anywhere outside `input` element, `onblur` handler is invoked hence `onclick` on `ul` element is not being executed.

`setTimeout` inside `onblur` handler would help!

```js
var ulClicked = false;
document.querySelector('input').onfocus = function() {
  document.querySelector('ul').style.display = "block";
}
document.querySelector('input').onblur = function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!ulClicked) {
      document.querySelector('ul').style.display = "none";
    } else {
      alert('UL clicked');
    }
    ulClicked = false;
  }, 100);
}
document.querySelector('ul').onclick = function(event) {
  ulClicked = true;
  document.querySelector('input').value = event.currentTarget.textContent.trim();
}
```

```html
<input/>
<ul style="display:none">
  <li>tiger</li>
</ul>
```